# Should it be "the response" or "responses" in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should it be "the response" or "responses" in this sentence?

> After reviewing the main features, benefits, and risks of fintech, this paper examined the domestic trend of fintech and **the response** by financial institutions, then inspected the financial stability with regard to fintech in South Korea. Currently, flagship financial services provided by domestic fintech companies include simple payment and remittance, peer-to-peer (P2P) finance, crowdfunding, initial coin offering (ICO), and robo-advisor.

Answer (score 0):

> After reviewing the main features, benefits, and risks of fintech, this paper examined the domestic trend of fintech and the response by financial institutions

As the financial **institutions** are likely to give more than one response, 'responses' should be the more appropriate term to use.  There is no indication in this example that the setup of this market framework requires the financial institutions to give a unified response.